# how to do group by shift multiply in dask data frame

Tags: dask

suppose my dask df looks like

```
date, stockticker, stock prediction, blahblahblah...
20100101, AAPL, 1,...
20100101, TSLA, 1,...
20100102, AAPL, -1,...
20100102, TSLA, -2,...
```

if it possible for me to do groupby shift?

```
ddf.set_index("date").groupby("stockticker").shift(1)?
```

This syntax does not work though...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently implemented in Dask DataFrame.  For feature requests, you may want to try the Dask issue tracker.